# cargar un datetimepicker con una hora existente en base de datos sql server

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una tabla en la base de datos en la cual un dato de esos es una hora; necesito cargarla en un datetimepicker, pero me salta el error de que no es el formato específico.

```
label10.Text = registro["Horario"].ToString();
```

Así pude hacer que se cargue la hora en un label, pero yo lo quiero en un datetimepicker, que es el mismo que guarda la hora.

```
datetimeoicker.Value = (DateTime)registro["Horario"];
```

Así me provoca el error que decía.

Comment: Y en que formato está la hora? y con qué tipo de dato está guardada en la base de datos?

Comment: En la base de datos esta guardada como time la hora!

Comment: Fijate en que formato tenes el datetime (que tiene una fecha y hora ;) )... tiene que mandarle el mismo formato...